# Error- Uncommitted Work Pending in test class. Trigger a future callout on record Update

Tags: callout, future, httpcalloutmock

I have trigger that makes a future callout when the record status changes to 'abc'. It working fine...End user updates the status to 'abc'. I am making a callout in method @future(callout=true).

Now , the problem is with the test class. What I am doing is simple.. Insert a record.. then update the status to 'abc'.. that will fire the trigger and hence the callout . I am handling callout with Mockresponse . However, I am getting an error that "You have uncommitted work pending". I searched and found out that making callout after DML is not allowed. However, Once I update the status I expect salesforce to make the callout in future as it defined. Is salesforce ignores @future in test classes. what's the best way to write a test class for such where updates (DML) trigger a callout.. Thanks.

Comment: did you use test.starttest() and test.stoptest() for testing in test class?

Comment: Are you using `Test.startTest();` and `Test.stopTest();` in the test class around the code that starts the callout?

Comment: Yes.. I put the update (DML) statement inside the Start() and Stop()..

Comment: If the future call makes a callout to a 3rd party system you have to implement mock callout class in your test. Have you done this?

Comment: Yes. I have implemented HttpCalloutMock.. and the error is not related to response. Salesforce is throwing callout exception and not making the callout itself.

Comment: The quickest path to success is to post some or all of the test code or we are just going to keep guessing at what the problem may be.

Comment: You may also be experiencing this known issue which is in review: [W-2979657](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eXOsAAM)

Comment: In addition to your test case code the debug log from the failed test case would also be useful.